# HttpContext.Current alternative in Owin Self Host?

Tags: c#, owin, rest, self-hosting

I am trying to get a File that is being sent (from Postman) in the body of a POST request to my REST API that is self hosted using Owin. While debugging I can confirm that the correct endpoint it being reached but HttpContext.Current returns null always. Pretty much HttpContext.*anything* returns null. So I don't understand how I am supposed to receive a File via POST request and process it in my REST API while using Owin self hosting. I have tried Request.GetOwinContext() but that doesn't return anything useful.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Request` property of a controller can help access the file.

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var multipartContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

            // "thefile" is the form field name
            HttpContent httpContent = multipartContent.Contents
                .Where(c => c.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"thefile\"")
                .Single();

            // httpContent contains the file, for example:
            var fileContents = await httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I get a ```Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.``` error on the ```var multipartContent = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();``` line. I added in the WebConfig ```config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));``` so I am not sure what would be causing this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with a small text file, maybe a few kilobytes? I wonder if this is a maximum request size.

Comment: I was sending an .rtf file with two paragraphs in it so about ~40kb @StephenJennings

Comment: Not sure then, this succeeds for me in a minimal console app, even if the file is several megabytes in size.

Comment: Weird. Well thanks for the suggestion, maybe I just need to find the right tweak to this snippet. Cheers @StephenJennings